# Deserialize string arrays in protocol buffer c++

Tags: c#, c++, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am sending an object that contain 2 string arrays from C# program to a C++ program with rabbitmq. The class in the C# program looks like this:

```
namespace LPRRabbitMq.Class
{
    [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
    public class BlackAndWhiteList
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string[] BlackList { get; set; }

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string[] WhiteList { get; set; }
   }
}
```

The code for the serialization of the object in C#:

```
 byte[] data;

 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
     Serializer.Serialize(ms, blackAndWhite);
     data = ms.ToArray();
 }
```

Now i want to get the data in the C++ program. I created a proto file:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package Protobuf;

message BlackAndWhiteList {
    optional bytes BlackList = 1;
    optional bytes WhiteList = 2;
}
```

I am receiving the message on the C++ program, but how can i deserialize the data and how to save eventually each string array in a seperate array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet here is to ask the library to help you out:

```
var proto = Serializer.GetProto<BlackAndWhiteList>(ProtoSyntax.Proto2);
```

This gives you:

```
syntax = "proto2";
package LPRRabbitMq.Class;

message BlackAndWhiteList {
   repeated string BlackList = 1;
   repeated string WhiteList = 2;
}
```

which tells you how best to represent it. By using `repeated` here, you should be able to correctly identify the individual elements in the C++ code. And by using `string`, it should come out as an appropriate type for C++.

Comment: Worked perfectly!